# How do I target specific audiences?

Tags: game-dev-tycoon

After researching "Target Audience", the game prompt tells you that certain consoles and genres appeal to certain audiences (Young, Everyone, Mature). Does targeting a specific audience properly actually boost your sales and, if so, how would you do so?

Comment: Related: [Which platforms are popular with which target audiences?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/115776/4797)

Answer (score 2):

Once you have researched Target Audience, an option for rating will be added to the initial game development options.  This is the audience you will be developing for.  The combination of target audience, topic, genre, and platform will affect game sales and the game will [let you know if your choices do not match.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/115776/which-platforms-are-popular-with-which-target-audiences)

[image]

Comment: You should add information about what Target Audiences do to fully answer the question.